# Google Sheets script to automatically locate cells with todays date, copy the whole row and send it via email

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I've built a reporting tool with google forms, where everyday I fill the forms, and the responses go to a spreadsheet. The spreadsheet has timestamp on column A, and the rest of the columns are the answers to the questions from the form.

I'm trying to write a script that will  send me everyday at a specific time an e-mail with an excel file/google sheet link, which will basically have a copy of all the answers from today's forms.(with the date stamp of the current day).

Can anyone help me get started with that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far i have a script that finds duplicates and highlights them, but it doesn't help me as much as i thought it would since it highlights the whole column A.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is

- a time [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)
- retrieve the timestamps backwards and push the rows with today's date into a value range array
- [create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname) a new spreadsheet
- [assign the value range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#createname) to the new sheet
- retrieve the [URL](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#geturl) of the new spreadsheet
- incorporate the URL into the [email to send](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body)

Here is a sample code incorporating this features, I encourage you to become more familiar with Apps Script, so that you can adapt this code to your needs:

```
function bindATimeTriggerToMe() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("PASTE-ID-OF-SPREADSHEET").getSheetByName("PASTE-NAME-OF-SHEET");
  var timestamps = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();

  var today = new Date();
  var i;
  for (i = timestamps.length-1; i > 0; i--){
    var day = timestamps[i][0];
    if (day.setHours(0,0,0,0) != today.setHours(0,0,0,0)){
      var firstRow = i + 2;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (firstRow){
    var rows = sheet.getLastRow()-firstRow+1;
    var columns = sheet.getLastColumn();
    var values = sheet.getRange(firstRow, 1, rows, columns).getValues();
    var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("results from "+ today);
    newSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(1, 1, rows, columns).setValues(values);
    var url = newSheet.getUrl();

    var recipient ="XXX@gmail.com";
    var subject = "results from " + today;
    var body = "Click on the following link: "+url;
    GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, that you must start to write code.

First I recommend reading about `Events` from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). There you can find two triggers:

- Google Sheets Events - Form Submit
- Google Form Events - From Submit

Pay attention to the difference between two types of trigger: **simple** and **installable**

Chose one of them, and use it for triggering some `MailApp.sendEmail()` function

Then i highly recommend to read documentation of SpreadSheet, Sheet and Range classes and try to write some code. When you catch a problem - write here with a piece of code that didn't work and describe your problem.

Good luck!